# Drop mysql tables in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

How do I drop selected tables in Rails? I want to drop all tables from a database with a given prefix. PHPMyAdmin would be very useful at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install phpMyAdmin and manually delete your tables, or if you wanted to do it from within the rails framework and keep you migrations in sync, why not create a new migration that drops the tables on self.up and creates the tables on self.down.

```
class DropOldTablesMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    drop_table :prefix_table1
    drop_table :prefix_table2
  end

  def self.down
    create_table :prefix_table1 do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
    end
    create_table :prefix_table2 do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
    end
  end
end
```

---

EDIT:
Just to follow up, if the issue is that there are a lot of tables and you don't want to type them all, you could do something like this:

```
class DropOldTablesMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
      unless t.index('yourprefix_') == nil
        drop_table t
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Of course you would not be able to recreate the tables when you migrate down that way, but depending on what is going on in your app, that may not be a concern.

---

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO YOUR COMMENT:

To create a new migration, from the root of your app run the following command:

```
script/generate migration YourMigrationName
```

The migration file will be created for you in db/migrate. Add the code you want to run and save it. To run the new file enter the following at the command line

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to Rails. I'm trying to install Wordpress in /public, so I would only have to drop my (broken) tables - Wordpress will handle the reinstallation.

So - I create e.g. db/migrate/001_drop_old_tables.rb, insert your code, minus the `self.down` bit, then run this?

How do I run it once I've deployed the new file?

Comment: I think you should just install phpmyadmin and drop the tables manually. It looks like it's not really related to your rails app.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Tomas in this case.

Comment: Running WP in public is going to cause all sorts of problems. You need to run on a subdomain or as a separate application on your server.

Comment: If you're running Passenger you can run wordpress side by side with you rails app in a directory http://www.abletech.co.nz/2009/06/serving-php-from-a-rails-app-with-passenger/

Comment: Thanks, I installed phpmyadmin.